# Compare strings in python of different type

Tags: python

I am getting two strings in the following way which contain integer values. I have tried all options but always got False as a result.

```
    string1    = element.__dict__.get('layer')    # '7'

    temp_string2,temp_string3=temp_key.split(':') # temp_key = '7:12'

    if string1 == temp_string2:
          print "data found"
```

I did not get True although both contain the same value. Can I have some input regarding this?

Comment: Could you add `print repr(string1), repr(temp_string2)` to your code to show us what the variables contain?

Comment: I got 7 and '7'. How will I fix this isssue. why is this diffirence.I got understanding that it would be string in both case

Comment: Also, why are you using `element.__dict__.get('layer')` instead of `element.layer`.

Comment: @user765443 -- are you comparing a `string` to an `int` ? try: `type(string1)`

Comment: @Martin I correct this mistake.I saw the existing code So I try to use same thing. I have element.layer which also gave me same thing

Comment: What does `type(element.layer)` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I saw in the comment stream

> Could you add print repr(string1), repr(temp_string2) to your code to
>   show us what the variables contain?
>
> I got 7 and '7'. How will I fix this isssue. why is this diffirence.I
>   got understanding that it would be string in both case

Its evident, you are comparing an integer with a string.

If `print repr(string1)`, returns `7` and `print repr(temp_string2)` returns `"7"` then `string1` , which is

```
string1    = element.__dict__.get('layer')
```

should be an integer

So you have to convert `string1` to `integer` before comparing

```
if str(string1) == temp_string2:
     print "data found"
```

or convert it to a string after retrieving the value from dictionary

```
string1 = str(element.__dict__.get('layer'))
```

Strangely enough, its a very unconventional way of accessing a the get method of the dict, instead you could have simply done a member referencing with `.` notation

```
string1    = element.get('layer')
```

Comment: Got the isssue. Thx Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Your final note about the weird access of the attribute is wrong, it's `element.layer` - `element` isn't a dict, the original was accessing it's `__dict__` then getting from that.

Answer (score 1):

`element.layer` is an `int`, not a `string`. This is why `repr(string1)` would return `7` and not `'7'`. You should try

```
string1` = str(element.layer)
```

Note at the same time that you shouldn't access object attribute through `__dict__` directly but with the `.` notation instead.